# How to set Client CA List on server QSslSocket?

Tags: qt, ssl, openssl

I use a pretty standard QTcpServer whose incomingConnection is overruled to do:

```
shared_ptr<QSslSocket> sock = make_shared<QSslSocket>(this);
sock->setSslConfiguration(p->mConfig);
if (sock->setSocketDescriptor(desc)) {
  sock->setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket::KeepAliveOption, true);
  ... code for handling ssl errors and other signals ...
  sock->startServerEncryption();
```

Here p->mConfig is a QSslConfiguration with correct invocations of setLocalCertificate(), setPrivateKey(), setCaCertificates(), setPeerVerifyMode(QSslSocket::VerifyPeer) and setCiphers() done on it.

This works, including the verification of the client certificate when the client provides one (and refusing connection when no or an invalid client cert is given).

When checking the server I noticed that openssl consistently reports "No client certificate CA names sent" for this server. This indicates that no SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list() call (or one of the alternatives with the same effect) was done on the context at OpenSSL level. Some TLS clients (in our case Java) use the client CA list in the handshake to select a client certificate from a set of client certificates they have in their key-store.

Not having the client CA list filled in, causes the client at hand to not provide any certificate, thereby failing connection. Of course, one path would be to correct the client, but all other servers (a.o. lighttpd) seem to operate correctly and also the openssl s_server will set the client CA list when given a -CAfile parameter.

I feel this should be corrected server-side in the Qt5 code that I'm running.

Is there some way to have Qt5 set the client CA list of a (server) QSslSocket?
If not, is there some (hack) to get the openssl context of a QSslSocket to myself add a hack to invoke SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list() on it with the correct CA certificate?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough the SSL under Qt to know offhand, and I don't have the time to research and formulate a full answer, but I suspect this is a good starting point for solving your problem: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsslsocket.html#setSslConfiguration

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the response, but I have checked all the documentation and even the source code of Qt to figure out whether / how I could set the client CA list before posting here ...  I've also done searches on all sorts of keyword combinations that could give me a hint into this topic, without finding much ...